# Python's strange behaviour with immutable lists

Tags: python, tuples

Why does python treats list of strings like this?..

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, May 27 2013, 05:35:12)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = ('sim')
>>> x[0]
's'
```

while mutable list does this...

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, May 27 2013, 05:35:12)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = ['sim']
>>> x[0]
'sim'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have an immutable `list` there. What you think you have is called a `tuple`, but it isn't. The parentheses are only there for grouping. You really just have an ordinary string. If you want to indicate a `tuple`, do so with a comma:

```
>>> x = ('sim')
>>> x
'sim'
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
>>> x = ('sim',)
>>> x[0]
'sim'
>>> type(x)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick version of the other answers (which are correct):
You must use a comma ',' in the parenthesis to make it a tuple. 
Without the comma you just have a string, and indeed the first index of that string is 's'.